# Passar um id "valor" para um campo input

Tags: php, input

Utilizo a seguinte function:

```
public function autoCompleteCilindro($q){

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->limit(5);
    $this->db->like('passo', $q);
    $query = $this->db->get('cilindros');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
            $row_set[] = array('label'=>'Impressora: '.$row['impressora'].'    |    Cilindro: '.$row['engrenagens'].'    |    Passo: '.$row['passo'].'    |    Quantidade: '.$row['quantidade'],'quantidade'=>$row['quantidade'],'id'=>$row['idCilindro'],'engrenagens'=>$row['engrenagens']);
        }
        echo json_encode($row_set);
    }
}
```

Digito o valor aproximado de um passo, 200 por exemplo e me é apresentado os campos da tabela "cilindros".

Isso eu faço em um campo input.

Preciso que seja passado para o campo "altura" o resultado da divisão do campo "passo" dividido pelo campo "quantidade.

```
                                    <div class="span6" style="margin-left: 0">
                                        <label for="impressora">Impressora  |  Engrenagem  |  Passo  |  Quantidade de Cilindros<span class="required"></span></label>
                                        <input name="impressora" id="impressora" class="span12" type="text" value="" />
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="span3">
                                        <label for="altura">Altura</label>
                                        <input name="altura"  id="altura" readonly class="span12" type="text" value="" />

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="span3">
                                        <label for="quantidade">Quantidade</label>
                                        <input name="quantidade" id="quantidade" class="span12" type="text"  value="" />
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Isso será feito por Ajax?

Comment: Acredito que sim. Dentro de uma estrutura de arquivos Models, tem um arquivo que tem as duas funtions public function adicionar e public function adicionarAjax().

Comment: "Acredita"? Vc não é o desenvolvedor da parada? Pelo visto, o Ajax retorna um JSON. Basta dividir um valor pelo outro e jogar no campo desejado.

Answer (score 0):

Se eu não tiver entendido errado, seria desta forma.

Veja o exemplo: https://pastebin.com/x6DuuQRX

Answer (score -1):

```js
function pesquisa(){
  var valorInput = document.getElementById('procura').value;
  $.post('/valida.php',{valor: valorInput},function(data){
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = data;
  })
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <input type="text" id="procura" onkeyup="pesquisa();">
 <button>Pesquisar</button>
</form>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Bom dia. Não sou expert ainda em PHP. Este arquivo "valida.php", crio ele? onde e para que serve ? Qual seria o seu código ?

Comment: Sim, vc cria ele em qualquer pasta. Por exemplo, se ele tiver na pasta /SITE/VALIDA.PHP então vc tem q colocar $.post('/site/valida.php',[...], dai no valida.php vc pega o valor do input com $_POST['valor']  e faz as validações que quiser. Mas pra vc testar vc pode dar echo $_POST['valor'] e vc vai entender

Comment: e seu conteúdo ?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp